# Changing night into day in Legend of Zelda: Skyward Sword

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

I cannot change night into day in Skyward Sword.

I just got the Goddess Sword and the first chunk of the Emerald Tablet. I am back at the Knight Academy. What does it mean you go to use the beds? I went to every bed and nothing happened.

Answer (score 8):

Walk up to any bed and press A, this will give you two options "sleep till morning" and "sleep till night."

Comment: I did that. I walk up to the bed and pressed " A " and nothing happens. Am i doing something wrong..

Comment: Have you tried going into Link's room and sleeping?

Comment: Just found out what i did wrong... I had to go back to the alter to place the chunk of Emerald in it's slot... thank you all for helping me.